# Бинарная куча барахлит

Tags: c++, heap

пытаюсь реализовать кучу. Есть код:

```
 void siftdown(int *&a, int i, const int size) //опускает элемент вниз, если 
{                                              //элемент меньше потомка
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;

    int largest = i;
    if (!(left > size) && !(a[left] < a[i]))
        largest = left;
    if (!(right > size) && !(a[right] < a[left]))
        largest = right;

    if (largest != i)
    {
        swap(a[i], a[largest]);
        cout << "large:" << largest << "  i:" <<i << endl;
        siftdown(a, largest, size);
    }
}


void buildheap(int *&a, const int size) //строит кучу
{
    for (int i = size / 2 - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        siftdown(a, i, size);
}

int main()
{

    int n, a = 0, i;
    cout << "enter the lenght of an array: ";
    cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    buildheap(arr, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << endl << "---------------------" << endl;
    buildheap(arr, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;


    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Нехитрым образом случайные элементы в массиве выстраиваются в кучу, но есть одно НО: при повторном вызове buildheap, уже полученная куча превращается в ересь.
Не могу понять, что не так. Оставлю скрин консоли. 
large - индекс наибольшего потомка, i - индекс текущего элемента, который сравнивается.
[image: консоль]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут уже наблюдается какая-то ерунда

```
int largest = i;
if (!(left > size) && !(a[left] < a[i]))
    largest = left;
if (!(right > size) && !(a[right] < a[left]))
    largest = right;
```

Ваша задача - найти индекс максимального элемента в тройке `a[i]`, `a[left]` и `a[right]`. Вышепроцитированный код делает это неправильно. Например, возьмем такую тройку

```
       40
      /  \
    10    20
```

Ваш код считает, что максимальным узлом в этой тройке является узел `a[right]`, т.е. `20`. А это, очевидно, не так.

Именно это проблема видна и вашем примере: `64` вдруг "победило" `78` и вылезло наверх в куче.

---

И в чем же заключается глубинный замысел постоянной передачи указателя по ссылке: `int *&a`???

Comment: я не понел чем код автора напоминает кучу?..

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Речь идет о классической структуре данных "heap", название которой обычно переводят как "куча". Совпадение терминов с "heap" в значении "динамическая память" существует и в английской, и в русской терминологии. О чем именно идет речь обычно ясно из контекста.

Comment: Еще бы обьяснили, что это не куча денег... Я спросил чем напоминает кучу, я не спрашивал где выделение памяти в куче...

Comment: "Кучу" она напоминает своей пирамидальной структурой - ровненькое [бинарное] дерево.

Comment: Не вижу там никакого дерева или я код не понел. Ну ладно, проехали...

Comment: понял, спасибо большое.
указатель уже был добавлен от отчаяния: долго не мог понять, чего так происходит.